# Proof of semicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

**Given Definition:**

Function $f$ on metric space $M$ is called *lower semicontinuous* if, for each real $a$ the set $\{x \in M: f(x) \leq a\}$ is closed in $M$.

**Question:**

Prove that $f$ is lower semicontinuous if and only if $f(x)\leq \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)$ whenever $x_n\to x$ in $M$.

**Hint Given:**

For the forward implication, suppose that $x_n\to x$ and $m = \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) \lt \infty$.
Then, for every $e>0$, the set $\{t \in M: f(t) \leq m + \epsilon \}$ is closed and contains infinitely many $x_n$.

This is from a Real Analysis book I am trying to read.
I would really like to share my work on this, but I do not seem to understand how to even begin with the proof, using only the definition given.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x_n$ converges to $x$. Let $\epsilon>0$, then the set $G_\epsilon=\{y\in M:\, f(y)>f(x)-\epsilon\}$ is open in $M$. Since, $x_n$ converges to $x$ there is an $m$ such that $x_n\in G_\epsilon$ for every $n\geq m$. In other words,
$$f(x_n)>f(x)-\epsilon$$
for every $n\geq m$. This implies that $\liminf_{n}f(x_n)\geq f(x)-\epsilon$. As $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary we have $\liminf_nf(x_n)\geq f(x)$. For the converse, suppose that whenever $x_n\to x$ we have $\liminf_{n}f(x_n)\geq f(x)$. We wish to show that the set $$F_\alpha=\{x\in M:\, f(x)\leq \alpha\}$$ is closed in $M$. We will show that the complement $$M\setminus F_\alpha=\{x\in M:\, f(x)>\alpha\}$$ is open. Pick $x\in M\setminus F_\alpha$, then $f(x)>\alpha$. If there is no $\rho>0$ such that the ball centered at $x$ with radius $\rho>0$ belongs to $M\setminus F_\alpha$ then we would be able to find a sequence $x_n\in F_\alpha$ such that $x_n\to x$. Then, since $x_n\in F_\alpha$ means that $f(x_n)\leq \alpha $ for all $n$, which implies $\liminf_n f(x_n)\leq \alpha$, contradicting our hypothesis $\liminf_n f(x_n)\geq f(x)>\alpha$. Hence, there is a $\rho>0$ such that the ball centered at $x$ with radius $\rho$ is contained on $M\setminus F_\alpha$. This means, that $M\setminus F_\alpha$ is open, hence $F_\alpha$ is closed as we wanted.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. And I am very happy that this is the way I tried to go about it, but I was uncertain if $f(x_n) > f(x) - \epsilon$ actually implied that $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\inf} f(x_n) \geq f(x) - \epsilon$. But seeing it now, it makes sense, since $x_0 \rightarrow x$. Thank you

Comment: There are some useful characterizations for inequalities like $\liminf_n y_n\geq y$ where in general $y_n$ is a sequence on $\mathbb{R}$. For example, $\liminf_n y_n \geq y$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{n\in \mathbb{N}:\, y_n<y-\epsilon\}$ is finite. In the answer above we showed that $f(x_n)>f(x)-\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$. In other words, the set $\{n\in \mathbb{N}:\, f(x_n)<f(x)-\epsilon\}$ is finite. Thats how we conclude $\liminf_n f(x_n)\geq f(x)$.